# Gitignoring md5 files

Tags: git, md5, gitignore

In one of my Git projects, I have files in `md5` format that I want to ignore.

I tried to add the following entry to my `.gitignore`,

```
[0-9a-f]{32}
```

but apparently `.gitignore` files do not support regexp. Is there an equivalent way to achieve that?

Comment: If you have any control over this, just give them a `.md5` extension. Blam.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over it, even I could not put it in a specific directory to ignore it.

Comment: 33? MD5 hashes are 32 chars long

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[0-9a-f]{32}` does not work,

but

```
[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]
```

does (although it is very ugly).

Answer (score 2):

`.gitignore` files use shell globbing, which doesn't support that sort of regex operation. If the files are all in a single directory, you could ignore that directory entirely. But in general, you can't use a regex in a `.gitignore` file to ignore these files.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `*.md5` to . gitignore